# I am stuck with logic maybe I am doing it wrong SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

**My query I tried so far**

```
select sum(g1.datacount) from
(select DAte(DATE) as 'newdate', COUNT(RIDE_ID) as 'datacount' from 
ride_Data
where date(date) between (now() - interval 90 day) and now()
group by date(date)
order by date(date) desc) as g1
where g1.newdate between (now() - interval 7 day) and now()
```

**the short version of the above query just for explanation.**

```
select sum(g1.datacount) from g1
where g1.newdate between (now() - interval 7 day) and now()
```

**What I want to achieve**
I want to sum last 7 days on column datacount as you can see I have done that part correctly now having any problem but in actual scenario I want sum last 90 days in group of 7 days pair
I don't know how to group that in such a way?

Is there anything like I can group by my last 7 record result

Comment: First you may want to figure out what DBMS you're really using and **only** tag that, not a bunch of them. Meanwhile I'll remove them.

Comment: SYSDATE for oracle!!!

Comment: Second you should [edit] the question and provide the schema as `CREATE TABLE` statements, some sample data as `INSERT INTO` statements and the desired result with that sample data.

Comment: @stickybit i thought the select query will be the same for most of the DBMS

Comment: No, it involves date/time stuff. That can vary greatly between them.

Comment: @stickybit ok added MySQL

Comment: how will you break 90 into 7 parts !!!

Comment: @nikhilsugandh  thought maybe with group by some variables or calculations ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compare against now, then you could use a DATEDIFF with a DIV 7 to group on.

```
SELECT ((DATEDIFF(t.newdate, NOW())) DIV 7) AS WeekDiff,
-- MIN(t.newdate) AS MinDate,
-- MAX(t.newdate) AS MaxDate,
 COUNT(t.RIDE_ID) as TotalRides
FROM ride_Data t
WHERE t.newdate BETWEEN (NOW() - interval 90 day) AND NOW()
GROUP BY WeekDiff
ORDER BY WeekDiff DESC;
```

Or maybe just group on the [week](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-week-function.php).

```
SELECT YEAR(t.newdate)*100+WEEK(t.newdate, 3) AS WeekNr,
COUNT(t.RIDE_ID) as TotalRides
FROM ride_Data t
WHERE t.newdate BETWEEN (NOW() - interval 90 day) AND NOW()
GROUP BY WeekNr
ORDER BY WeekNr DESC;
```